# Excel/VBA: Finding rows based on field match and counting non-blank values

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have an excel file containing two sheets. The first sheet contains a list of names and a total column. The second sheet MAY contain a name from the first sheet and one or more dates entered into three columns. For each name in sheet1 (column A) I would like to search sheet2 and count the number of entries for each name in Column B, Column C and Column D. Those counts need to be three separate values.

[image: Sheet1]

[image: Sheet2]

Eventually i'm going to apply a weighting value to each of those counts and sum everything up - resulting in a numeric value for each name.

I'm presuming I can use a for each loop in VBA, something like:

```
  For Each Item In XXX
      Myname = othername 
   Next
```

But I really don't know how to get counts by column and set those as variables?

Comment: You can use `CountIf` , I don't think you need VBA for it.

Comment: Depending on the number of criteria, `CountIfs()` could be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

**Example Formula:**

```
=COUNTIFS($H$2:$H$21,$A2,I$2:I$21, "<>")
```

- References in the GIF below. You can manipulate the formula as per your need.

**Demo:**

[image]

Comment: very interesting function, thanks all. I'll work with the syntax!